# Any way to terminate NPM process when running it programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an Electron-based app where by user request NPM installs missing dependencies. I use NPM like that:

```
const npmlog = require( "npm/node_modules/npmlog" ),
      npm = require( "npm" );


 npm.load({
    loaded: false,
    progress: false,
    "ignore-scripts": true,
    "no-audit": true
  }, ( err ) => {
...

npm.commands.install( appInstallDirectory, [
      "cross-env@^5.2.0",
      "jest@^23.6.0",
      "puppeteer@^1.10.0",
      "shelljs@^0.8.2"
    ], ( err, data ) => {
...
   });
});
```

I have a modal window, which displays the install process and hides when it's done. All is fine with it, but I want to add button that can be clicked to terminate the process, not Electron process, but NPM. In perfect world one clicks the button, the modal window closes, NPM stops and the user proceeds with the app (Electron still running).

Any suggestions?

Comment: To clarify: you only want to stop npm from continuing. The electron app should keep going.

Comment: Yeah, that's true

Comment: if you ran npm as an external process (`let myChildProcess = child_process.spawn('npm',['install'])`) you could use  `myChildProcess.kill()`

Comment: That I can of course , but I use it programatically to make it working even when client machine has no node.js/NPM installed, cross-platform